# How to improve performance of UICollectionView with custom cell sizes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

As the user types, I am retrieving results (text) by traversing a local word graph in a background thread.  Each keystroke cancels the previous operation.  If the operation completes, the data source is updated and reloadData is called on the main thread.  This works great and is very fast (as fast as the user can type), even when tens of thousands of results are returned.

To customize the size of each collection view cell, I implemented sizeForItemAtIndexPath for the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate.  Unfortunately, this results in a small, but noticeable lag when the user types.  To be sure the time was not lost in my size calculation logic, I tried just returning a fixed size, but it still killed performance.  I am surprised at this because there are only ~120 cells or so on the screen at any given time.  When commenting out this method, the response time is again immediate, even for very large data sets.

Any ideas for improving the performance of UICollectionView with custom cell sizes?

Thanks

Additional clarification...

The program returns all possible words from the given set of letters then sorts by score or alphabetically, etc.  As the user types, the total word count goes up fast (exponentially, if multiple wildcards are entered).  The words change as you type so the width of the cells update accordingly and wrap to the next line as handled by the flow layout.

The issue seems to be the number of cells shown on the screen at any given time.  In sizeForItemAtIndexPath, if I just return a large size where only one or two cells are visible, the update is very fast; however, if I return a size that just fits the text, I end up with 100+ visible cells and there is a lag.  If I comment out sizeForItemAtIndexPath and just use a fixed size cell, it is fast, but that is not what I am going for.

Comment: Are you wanting the cells to change size during typing or just have fixed custom sizes?

Comment: Trying to understand why you're calling `reloadData` rather than just updating the cells on screen.

Comment: Additional clarification added above... The width of the cells change as the user types.  How would I do this without calling reloadData?

Comment: My current theory is that you're causing the entire layout to reflow, which could conceivably take a long time if you've got enough (tens of thousands) items. It could be that the two scenarios where you say it's fast (fixed sizes and large sizes) are not reflowing the whole thing due to some layout optimizations. Have you tried limiting the result set to, say, 100 items?

Comment: Also, can you try profiling it? And are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: Timothy, It is definitely better when I restrict the datasource to a few hundred items.  I can just add a "More..." cell and let the user retrieve additional cells if needed.  With this approach, I can still update a label with the actual count in (close to) real time.

Comment: I do have auto layout turned on in my storyboard, but the cells are not fully constrained (only align center Y and align center X).  I still need to do some profiling w/ Instruments.

Comment: If it's an easy thing to do, you might want to try without Auto Layout. I imagine the Auto Layout system has to solve a linear program, which is an iterative process. I don't know how well it scales, but something to try.

Comment: Turning off auto layout did not help in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reload `UICollectionView` by calling `reloadData` , instead you can use:

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
```

Here, `indexPath` is the `NSIndexPath` object for the corresponding `UICollectionViewCell` object
that you want to update.

Comment: I like the idea of looping through the data using insertItemsAtIndexPaths or reloadItemsAtIndexPaths which gives me the opportunity to keep checking to see if the NSOperation isCancelled (i.e., user typed a new letter).  So far, I have been unable to get this to work.  I'll try again tonight...

Comment: As I understand it, the entire layout is reflowing, so you can't just reload select items. The layout actually has to get invalidated.

Comment: I still don't see how I can avoid doing a reloadData, considering the entire data source (word list) changes with every keystroke (including cell widths).

Here is the general flow of my program: 1. textDidChange cancels all operations, 2. adds NSOperation to queue (only 1 concurrent), 3. operation calls method to find words from letters in background (aborts if cancelled), 4. updates data source with found words (if not cancelled), 5. reloadData on main thread (if not cancelled).

Comment: I was thinking maybe I could do my own loop in step 5 to manually insertItemsAtIndexPaths so I can keep checking for isCancelled, but I still can't get that to work.  Thoughts?

Comment: This is the right answer for most cases.  In my specific case, there was no way to avoid the reloadData so I am just limiting the numberOfItemsInSection to a smaller number then providing a "Load More" button.